# Creating coloured map from Excel using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, mapping

I have an Excel file with some data and I want to create a map and present data with colours. I do everything well except for I present my data with dots. Instead, I need to cover the free space with an average of neighbour dots so as to have a solid map. Check out the photos to understand what I am saying.

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want to make:

[image]

All the above has to be done in ArcMap.

Comment: Something like this has been covered here before, see if that's what you're after.
[Creating Surface from points](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101957/creating-surface-from-points-in-arcgis-for-desktop)